# How should I implement in android Presentation slide in images file?

Tags: android, image, viewflipper, presentation, picturegallery

I would like to convert my presentation file (.ppt) into images then put it on app. It just just plain presentation with the ability for me to swipe left or right to change slides (images in this case). What method is the easiest? viewflipper? Picture galery? or any SDK ready for this? Sample code or URL will be great as I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you

```
SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(new HSLFSlideShow("slideshow.ppt"));

  //extract all pictures contained in the presentation

  PictureData[] pdata = ppt.getPictureData();

  for (int i = 0; i < pdata.length; i++){

    PictureData pict = pdata[i];

    // picture data
    byte[] data = pict.getData();

    int type = pict.getType();

    String ext;

    switch (type){

      case Picture.JPEG: ext=".jpg"; break;

      case Picture.PNG: ext=".png"; break;

      case Picture.WMF: ext=".wmf"; break;

      case Picture.EMF: ext=".emf"; break;

      case Picture.PICT: ext=".pict"; break;

      default: continue;

    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict_"+i + ext);

      out.write(data);

      out.close();

  }
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan. If I understand correctly, the above help me to convert my slide into picture file? what I need is to have viewer for the images instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with ViewPager. native control in android.
You can find sample code as well as more detail about control in this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).